# Bot Framework Task Module as a Skill

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm implementing a [Teams Task Module](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module) as a bot framework skill as shown in sample [80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot). and following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) I'm using the simple-root-bot in sample 80 to consume the Teams Task Module skill. I'm using c#

When I run the root-bot and invoke the skill I get "Unable to reach app" when invoking the task module (see image). [Teams Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmpZ0.png)

I have deployed the skill directly to Teams (same code, same App ID) without using the root bot and it's working. The problem seems to be when the bot is consumed by another bot as a skill. I have tried both the adaptive card task module and the HTML iframe task module to test whether it could be a problem with "ValidDomains" in the manifesto but which would only cause the iframe task module to fail but both task modules show the same error.